# Query like "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" in Zend

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a question about prepare() method. I have a query like this one :

```
public function updateParam($id, $param, $value){
    // Change BDD
    $db = Zend_Registry::get("db_foo");
    // Prepare query
    $insert = $db->prepare( 
    'INSERT INTO TP_bar (id, type, value)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    value = ?');        
    // Execute query
    $insert->execute(array($id, $param, $value, $value));                
}
```

With that synthax, I have to duplicate $value in my execute, there is any other issue to do this without duplicate ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value)
```

See also the docs for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, specifically:

> You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to
>   refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. In other words, VALUES(col_name) in
>   the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause refers to the value of col_name
>   that would be inserted, had no duplicate-key conflict occurred. This
>   function is especially useful in multiple-row inserts. The VALUES()
>   function is meaningful only in INSERT ... UPDATE statements and
>   returns NULL otherwise. Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);
```